# We should get "Ubuntu questions on SR" notification in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

In general chat room, we get notification for **Ubuntu questions on U&L**.
[image]

I think it would be a good idea to get **Ubuntu questions on SR** notification as well.

> SR stands for [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), the newly released Stack Exchange site which is currently in public beta.

Comment: I think that before you answer any of those questions, you would need to read [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/455/226), [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/226) and in case of questions, [this one.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/226)

Comment: Also check the [FAQ](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: That would be interesting. But I think it would get too disruptive.